# Parsing .txt files in Json format with a java in knime

Tags: java, json, knime

I have .txt files with some junk at the top then json format. I need to parse them and pull strings from the json part and get these strings into a knime workflow. I have been trying to use a java snippet, but I can't get it to work. It doesn't have to be done in Knime, but I have about 30 files with 100 strings needing to be pulled from each.

Comment: You need to give examples of what you are trying to do. And show what you tried.

Comment: So, you have no junk after the JSON content. I doubt there are JSON parsers that can read JSON from the end (KNIME's JSON parser is certainly incapable to do so), so you should remove first the junk from the beginning, than parse the rest with the String To JSON node, after that you can use the JSONPath node to select the parts you need.